# Jira. How to set the issue creator when importing via JSON?

Tags: json, csv, import, jira

when I import a issue via JSON, Jira sets the creator of the issue to the user who imported the issue, and not to whom has reported it.

Is there a field where I can set the creator?

Here is my sample JSON file. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BNZ6A29Q)

Edit:
And here is a picture of what I mean. I (Sascha) am only the importer and not the creator. "vanderma" (Meer) should be the creator.
[image]

Comment: Did you had any succes on this?

Comment: unfortunately not... seems like the creator always has to be the importer..

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has:

```
"assignee": "vanderma",
"reporter": "vanderma",
```

Just change the `reporter` value in the JSON to the user that actually reported it and you're done :)

Comment: No, the "assignee" and "reporter" fields are correct. 
the problem is, that Jira sets me (Sascha) as creator, and not the user who actually reported it (vanderma). 
I will upload a pic

Answer (score 0):

help someone who search this question from google.

Jira has set this issue invalid:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-62308

> Oswaldo Hernandez (Inactive) added a comment - 24/Aug/2016 7:14 AM
>
> Hi Ismael Olusula Jimoh,
>
> This is expected and by design. The issue creator is always set to the
> logged in user who actually performed the "issue create" operation (in
> this scenario via import) and should be immutable.
>
> Regards,
>
> Oswaldo Hernández. JIRA Bugmaster. [Atlassian].

and there is a walkaround method: update your jira database directly.

```sql
update jiraissue set creator=reporter;
```